# Show time series for all hosts in grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am building some grafana monitors to watch many hosts.  As an example, one plots free disk space, and I see a separate plot for each host.  The main interesting thing is any hosts that show periodic or secular drops.

I have a variable and group by $host, but it seems I'm obliged to show the dropdown menu so that I can explicitly select "all hosts".  But I'd prefer not to have that menu there at all, just programmatically select all hosts every time.

```
SELECT percentile("free", 5)
FROM "autogen"."disk"
WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/)
  AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($__interval), "host"
```

[image]
[image]

Is this possible?  Or am I confused in even wanting this?

Answer (score 0):

In the template variable setting for $host, select variable under Hide menu.[image]